# Android Center Buttons

Tags: android

How do I center a button and make it so it is 10px off of each side. Basicly 100% wide minus 10px on the left and right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try that:

```
layout_width="fill_parent"
layout_marginLeft="10dip"
layout_marginRight="10dip"
```

Comment: dip stands for display independent pixels which calculates the unit into the real pixel. Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for much more information

Answer (score 8):

You can set maragin left and mariagn right,If you had used Relative Layout then you can make use of the following parameters 
**layout_centerInParent, android:layout_centerVertical, android:layout_centerHorizontal**

If you want to center the Button in Vertical then use Center vertical true , or if you want to center Button in Horizontal then use Center Horizontal true
as shown i below

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="SignUp Here"
    android:id="@+id/mysignup"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mylogin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" <!--  use depending upon your need -->
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" <!--   use depending upon your need -->
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" <!--  use depending upon your need -->
/>
```

Dip refers to Density Indepent Pixels, this is means,  if you had set the value of 10 ,  it's same for all device, where as px(pixels) takes absolute value,  so your alignment may go wrong in some devices, that's why, also make a not of it , you can use dip as dp too, compiler converts dp to dip

Answer (score 3):

First: forget about pixel, always use dp as unit.
Do you want to add it programaticaly or via layout xml files?

If you need to add it programaticaly use this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText("Some label");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            1);
    params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(button);
```

If you would like to add it from layout file do like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<Button android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scroll_story_title"
    android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2" android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Something to show to the user and that's pretty cool"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
```